# calculus of variations or optimize over function form

Tags: probability-theory, optimization, calculus-of-variations, information-theory

I have a question about optimizing the following quantity over function form .

Given unknown function  $f(\theta)$  such that $f(\theta)\geqslant 0$ and $\int f(\theta)d\theta\leq \infty$. And function $p(\theta)$ is unknown, and maybe we have one more conditon that   $\int p(\theta)d\theta=1$.

The goal is to optimize the following integral over function form $p(\theta)$,

$ \max_{p(\theta)} \int p(\theta)\log \frac{f(\theta)}{p(\theta)}d\theta$.

Many notes say that based on elementary exercise in calculus of variations, one can show that the function $p(\theta)$ ,which is proportional to function $f(\theta)$, maximizes the integral, i.e. $p(\theta)\propto f(\theta)$ .

But I have no idea how to do it. Could anyone show me how to maximize the integral using the technique of calculus of variation ? Besides this quantity is very important in information theory.
thank you

Comment: How much do you know about calculus of variations? Have you tried taking the derivative of the integral w.r.t. $p$?

Comment: I do not have experience with that topic, charles. thx

Answer (score 1):

Without going into too much detail, an extremum w.r.t. $p$ happens as a solution to the [Euler-Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Euler.E2.80.93Lagrange_equation), which for this functional happens when $p=\frac{1}{e}f$.

EDIT: A "little" more detail: in the first case, the *Lagrangian* is given by $L=L(x,p,p')=p(x)\log\frac{f(x)}{p(x)}=p\left(\log f-\log p\right)$, and since $L$ doesn't depend explicitly on $p'$, the Euler-Lagrange equation is
$$0=\frac{dL}{dp}-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dL}{dp'}=(\log f-\log p)+p\left(-\frac{1}{p}\right)=\log f-\log p-1=\log\frac{f}{e}-\log p,$$
giving the solution mentioned above.

If then the Lagrangian $L=p(x)\log\frac{f(p(x))}{p(x)}$, the EL-equation is a little more complicated:
$$0=(\log f(p)-\log p)+p\left(\frac{f'(p)}{f(p)}-\frac{1}{p}\right)$$
$$\Longrightarrow \frac{p}{f(p)}=\exp\left(\frac{p}{f(p)}f'(p)\right),$$
for which I cannot imagine a way to solve for $p$ in general, so this situation is not the same.

Comment: ah...In the problem, I mentioned that the solution is proportional to function $f$. So it is your result. Hi charles, I have one more problem about this. If I know somehow, f is also a function of $p$. But at the first stage, I pretend that f is known and has nothing to do with p. So we know that $p=f/e$ maximizes the integral. Next stage, since $f=f(p)$, I solve the equation $p=f(p)/e$ for p, then I also have the p that maximizes the integral right?  thank you